# Coloured PointCloud rendering JavaScript algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, 3d, pseudocode, point-clouds

I've just made a 3D **pointcloud** rendering app in JS. This app is able to render +200 000 3D black/white points at 40 FPS for dense heavy clouds. However, I'm now trying to implement **colours**, and, while I was working on this new feature, I realised that the order in which points were painted on the screen was really important.

**I've made another file where I've selected a colour for each point. For example, point 0 is red, point 1 is green and point 2 is blue; so colours are precalculated.**

I mean, **points that are further** from the user **should be rendered first** and points that are closer should be rendered later. With this technique, if two points **overlap**, the point which is closer is the one which will appear on the screen.

I made a custom algorithm [O(n^2) pretty slow I know] which sorted all the points (more than 200 000) for the distance from the position of the user (further points first). However, it takes me about 7 seconds to put them in the right order, for and app which was intended to be real-time, and I had to make a workaround for preventing the browser from showing a "this page is not responding" popup.

> Is there any other method for rendering 3D coloured points which overlap on the screen? Don't worry, I'm not asking for a piece of code, I just want to know if there's another faster way to achieve this, if possible in pseudo-code.

*I already know that I can reduce that time writing a more efficient algorithm but that would still be too slow. Every valid answer will be rewarded with an upvote!*

**THIS IS WHAT I'VE GOT SO FAR**

[image]

**THIS IS WHAT I'D LIKE TO HAVE**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you came up with your `O(n^2)` time complexity.

You have your array of 200k points. You have some point to which you have to calculate a distance. This is done in `O(n)`. On my machine it is done in `42.142ms`.

Now you have to sort your points based on this distance and on my machine it done in `122.358ms`. Your sorting algorithm runs in `O(n*log(n))`. Now you draw the points from furthest to closes and it also runs in `O(n)`.

So I am not sure how you ended up with `O(n^2)` and why it runs in 7 seconds.

Comment: I'm currently using a method I made based on the Selection Sort algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) which seems to be O(n^2).

Comment: It does the following:

Comment: 2. Sort every point taking into account the previous information so further points are the first ones (selection sort): O(n^2)

Comment: @BrainOverflow and why exactly are you doing this? You have 1 `3d` point, and many other points. You need to calculate `sqrt((x - x1)^2 +(y - y1)^2 +(z - z1)^2)` and this is your distance. Add it as additional parameter to each point in your array of points. Then sort it with a native sort function. Do not reinvent the wheel, especially if the wheel becomes less round :-).

Comment: you're so right about that xD. That comment deserves another upvote

Comment: I'll try to squeeze as many native functions as I can, because they seem to preform much better than my square shaped wheels xD

Comment: @BrainOverflow not only this, your wheel also has bigger time complexity.

Comment: true. I've tested it out and now i am able to render them correctly in about 500ms. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @BrainOverflow can you please post the link to the app, once you will finish it? P.S. check the time of sorting, your whole app should not run significantly slower than that time.

Comment: I don't think that my app will be realeased online. it was just intended to be a diy challenge xD. However, I can provide you some stats if you want so. I'm testing it out right now and it runs steady at 60FPS both in low resolution and HD provided 14K different points. Note that I'm not using webgl and all calculations are made on the CPU; this includes the point sorting which is carried out using browser's native <Array.sort>.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting, you could memorize the rendered pos / distances during the rendering. If you find that a new point that you're about to render is farther than an overlapping point that is already rendered, you skip the new point.

Comment: that's a good one! However, most of the times, points don't overlap 100% so a part of the point behind can still be seen. However, that seems to be the best idea so you earned a +1!

Comment: If you want real-time rendering I think you have to cut some corners and find a balance between speed and accurracy. Is 500ms / frame fast enough for you ?

Comment: Not at all xD. It has to run at last at 30FPS so that's quite far off. In order to enhance the user experience, I decided to sort the pointcloud only when the user is still and it's been like that for about 100ms. Presumably, they will be looking around the map and the app will have enough time to complete the whole process before the user moves again. **if you have any suggestion, please let me know it :)**

Comment: Well, first there's an easy optimisation: don't sqrt the distances, it doesn't change the ordering. BTW, it would be interesting to profile the rendering to see what is the cost of sorting and what is the cost of distance calculation.

Comment: you're right dude. I didn't even think about the sqrt thing.

Comment: Without optimizing the distance measurement, it's currenlty painting 14K points at 60 FPS in HD. I'm really shocked as all the calculations are CPU based and webgl isn't used at all.

Comment: However, when I provided a 212K dense pointcloud the fps rate dropped to 30 so I disabled the real-time point sorting, as I told you before.

Comment: **> points don't overlap 100%**

How large are your "points" ? If your points are made of several pixels, you can create a discrete coordinates system by rounding screen coordinates into a grid, so that a given x,y contains at most a single point. That would boost rendering times a lot, because you could avoid rendering a lot of points if the cloud is dense.

Comment: that's true but my points are just of the size of a pixel (when they're further they can be even less). That optimization would still be somewhat possible, but I don't think that this would improve the performance though as I would have to organize them into a new gird (extra memory), then compare the coordinates of the gird and eventually put the points in order knowing its position on the gird. But I'll take it into account too and maybe i'll implement it later. Thanks a lot :) as I said before, your help is really appreciated and new suggestions are also welcome

Comment: By the way, the time consumption of the distance calculation is really small compared to the sorting process `O(n)   VS   O(n log n)`

Comment: If points are 1 pixel at most, a point closer overlaps 100% of a point farther, doesn't it ?

Comment: not really. Sometimes, that may happen, but most of the time the closer point only hides a small part of the point behind. This drawing is a good example of that: http://www.parkablogs.com/sites/default/files/depth-techniques-02.jpg check it out. If I haven't been too clear let me know and I'll try to explain it better

Comment: You said that your points were "just of the size of a pixel", so I assumed that you were doing a pixel-per-pixel rendering, and so that it would be possible to use a simple XY array containing the distances of the pixels that were already drawn. I would be interested to know more about your app, else it's hard to discuss this line of possible optimisations.

Comment: I'll try to give a brief explanation of what it does: first, it takes the point coordinates in 3D and moves them according to the viewpoint, then it rotates them as desired, after that, the application calculates the position of the projection of the point on the screen and eventually that point is drawn using anti-aliasing painting techniques according to its colour, size and position.

Comment: In the last step, the order in which points are drawn is really important, since closer points should be painted last in order to avoid incorrect colour overlapping. And, that's basically what I've made so far, I hope it's clear now. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98668/discussion-between-ilya-and-brainoverflow).